# Jaeger configuration for class library

Tags: c#, .net-core, jaeger, opentracing

I am trying to incorporate Jaeger and OpenTracing into my Class Library project in .Net core.

Most of the Jaeger documentation shows how to configure Jaeger for Web API's in Startup.cs file.

The below configuration works for .Net core API project

```
 services.AddSingleton<ITracer>(serviceProvider =>
            {
                string serviceName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;

                ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();

                ISampler sampler = new ConstSampler(sample: true);

                ITracer tracer = new Tracer.Builder(serviceName)
                    .WithLoggerFactory(loggerFactory)
                    .WithSampler(sampler)
                    .Build();

                GlobalTracer.Register(tracer);

                return tracer;
            });
```

but I would like to configure the same for my Class LIbrary project. Is it possible ?
I mean for example someone else uses my class library in their App I should be able to see the tracing.
The Jaeger configuration should be made in Class LIbarary.

Comment: Class libraries shouldn't do DI, that's the application's responsibility. Create a static (extension) method to hide this ugliness, and call `YourLibrary.DI.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection)` to set it all up.

Comment: The DI code snippet I provided above was to just show how it is done in WEB API, I do not Have a WEB API project. I only have a class LIbrary and this Class LIbrary could be used by Non WEB API, may be some other project triggers this class library. Imagine if Jaeger is running on a port, how could I add tracing to my Class Library by providing Jaeger configuration to my Class LIbrary itself ?